# How to conditionally skip tests based on runtime information?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to programmatically skip some tests based on runtime information? For example, I would like `cargo test` to emit something like

```
test my_test ... skipped
```

instead of

```
test my_test ... ok
```

when `cond()` is evaluated to `false` in the following test:

```
#[test]
fn my_test() {
    if !cond() {
        // Mark the test as skipped. How?
        return;
    }

    // The actual test that works only when cond() returns true.
}
```

In other words, I am looking for a Rust alternative of [`unittest.skipTest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.skipTest) in Python ([more information](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest-skipping)).

Answer (score 16):

There is nothing built in for this; tests only succeed or fail.

The built in test runner is very minimal.