# How to skip a test in Rust based on a constant?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I have a constant

```rust
const SIZE: usize = 8;
```

and I have a bunch of tests. Some tests are for when this constant is larger than 8, some for when its lower than 8, as I test some special cases. How can I skip tests based on this?
For example, one such test uses the type `u8`, and cannot be used if the `SIZE` is larger than 8.
Based on [How to conditionally skip tests based on runtime information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557542/how-to-conditionally-skip-tests-based-on-runtime-information), there is no way to do this at runtime, but since I have everything at compile time, is there a way looking like

```rust
#[cfg(SIZE <= 8)]
```

to compile this test only if the constant is in the right range?

Example of test

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
  use super::SIZE;
  #[test]
  fn will_panic_if_size_small() {
    assert!(SIZE > 8);
  }

  #[test]
  fn will_panic_if_size_big() {
    assert!(SIZE <= 8);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How does `SIZE` change in value at compile time? If it's based on, say, the bytes in a `usize`, you can use [`#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "64")]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#target_pointer_width)

Comment: @PitaJ It changes based on the size of a system I want to use, for a scientific simulation. Say I want 84 spins, then I would use the smallest data structure that can fit it, u128 in this case or a custom byte array. This is not really a parameter to the system, as it does not need to change during the simulation, but is required to be changed and recompile when using another size. It is important to be a constant because the string of bit lives on the stack and its size needs to be known at compile time.

Comment: I would recommend using a cargo feature to switch between `SIZE` values. Then you can use the same feature to gate the tests.

Comment: @PitaJ That would be the best I believe, but for the time being I have not found how to pass an arbitrary value through a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is still not possible. Macros cannot evaluate `const`s, as they are executed before constant evaluation, so it is equivalent to runtime condition.